# Server tag is not well formed error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've this issue with my asp.net c# coding. It says there is an error: " server tag is not well formed". Below is my c# code.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID='ImageButton6' runat="server" BackColor="White"
     ImageUrl="~/Images/fb.png" Height="40px" OnCommand="ImageButton6_Command"/>
```

Comment: `ID='ImageButton6'` is in single quotes. May be this is the reason.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tested, and although single quotes look weird, it doesn't generate an error

Are you sure that line is the one that is creating that error. Can you add the entire markup, or at least the markup around the code you put in above

Comment: delete the code, build the project, re-add the image button without pasting. I think it's something in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the section `ID='ImageButton6'`. Don't use mix of single and double quote. You should be using double quotes only. In case chosen then use only single quotes.

Comment: Hi i tried double quotes but it still has the same error

Comment: @denissapop, then post your design code. that line is not the culprit then